# Distribute Ok and Cancel button equally in Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have this problem with alert dialog button
I have successfully added some data in database using this

[image]

but what i am aiming is like this
[image]

any help will be appreciated :)
and here is my code

```
mylistView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                        View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_prompt_attendance, null);
                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);
                        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Attendance:");

                        alertDialogBuilder
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                                    }

                                })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();

                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog alertD = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                        alertD.show();

                    }
                });
```

this is thepromptAttendance xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
tools:context="com.ucu.ccs.classrecord.promptAttendance">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="Date"/>
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/present"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Present"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/absent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Absent"/>
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the promptAttendance java file

```
public void goAdd(View view){
    new AttemptGetData().execute();
}

class AttemptGetData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    String date = Date.getText().toString();
    String remarks = RadioAttBtn.getText().toString();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(promptAttendance.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("In Progress...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        List<NameValuePair> mList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        mList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", date));
        mList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("remark", remarks));

        Log.d("starting", "fetch");

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", mList);

        try {
            verify = json.getString("Message");
            return verify;
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (s != null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), verify, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Date.setText(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: pls provide activity_prompt_attendance

Comment: @RajeshJadav hi sir i added both xml and java file

Comment: why not trying adding buttons in your custom layout only ?

Comment: @MohammadhussainKhatri I did but I want the default button of alert dialog coz its more presentable :)

Comment: hmm. @JeffreyZamucoOliveras , so the answer below will work. But I would recommend to custom buttons , as you can have any kind of customizations in styling you want, as you already using custom layout.

Answer (score 1):

weight is not working for me (my test phone is galaxy s3 5.0.1)

[image]


so I change little bit.

```
  alert.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            Button posButton = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            Button negButton = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
            View parent =(View)posButton.getParent();
            parent.setPadding(0,0,0,0);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams posParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) posButton.getLayoutParams();
            posParams.width = parent.getWidth()/2;
            posParams.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams negParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) negButton.getLayoutParams();
            negParams.width = parent.getWidth()/2;
            negParams.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

            posButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#222222"));
            negButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#222222"));
            posButton.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15);
            negButton.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15);
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15503093)

Comment: It's not a question. my bad I followed the **Rajesh**'s answer but it's not working so I made change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `OnShowListener` and override its `onShow(DialogInterface dialog)` method to set `OK` and `CANCEL` button's width according to `AlertDialog's` width

Android Documentation says:

> **OnShowListener:**
>
> *Interface used to allow the creator of a dialog to run some code when
>   the dialog is shown.*
>
> **public abstract void onShow (DialogInterface dialog)**
>
> *This method will be invoked when the dialog is shown.*
>
> **Parameters:**  *dialog - The dialog that was shown will be passed into the method.*

You can set this code after this line:

```
AlertDialog alertD = alertDialogBuilder.create();
```

Here is code:

```
alertD.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {

    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface d) {
        Button posButton = alertD.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        Button negButton = alertD.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);

        LayoutParams posParams = (LayoutParams) posButton.getLayoutParams();
        posParams.weight = 1;
        posParams.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

        LayoutParams negParams = (LayoutParams) negButton.getLayoutParams();
        negParams.weight = 1;
        negParams.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

        posButton.setLayoutParams(posParams);
        negButton.setLayoutParams(negParams);
    }
});
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: hi sir what is mRateConcertDialog by the way where it came from?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Kotlin example.

Note: There is a `Space` in the AlertDialog layout that has `layout_weight = 1.0f`, so setting a really high `weight` for each dialog button will shrink the spacer to nothing. Or you can find it (`R.id.spacer`) and hide it.

```
dialog.setOnShowListener {
                dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE)?.apply {
                    updateLayoutParams<LinearLayout.LayoutParams> {
                        width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                        weight = 100000.0f
                    }
                }
                dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE)?.apply {
                    updateLayoutParams<LinearLayout.LayoutParams> {
                        width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                        weight = 100000.0f
                    }
                }
            }

            dialog.show()
```